# How to fix 'GDrive API file.list not able to detect specific files in a parent folder'

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api

## I want to fetch file id's on google drive within a single folder. Files cannot be identified for each week. Assume the following folder structure:

- Product_A_CW20.csv
- Product_C_CW21.csv
- Product_A_CW19.csv
- Product_C_CW10.csv
- Product_B_CW12.csv
- Product_F_CW08.csv

### The unique identifier for files that I want to fetch is the calendar week.

```py
def fetch_file_id(week, service, parent_id):
    #Call the Drive v3 API and fetch file id
    results = service.files().list(q="'" + parent_id + "' in parents 
    and fullText contains '" + 'CW' + str(week) + "'",pageSize=30, 
    fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()

    items = results.get('files', [])
```

### My code is not able to find file id's with calendar weeks between 10 and 19:

- Product_A_CW19.csv
- Product_C_CW10.csv
- Product_B_CW12.csv

Comment: In your situation, when only `q="'" + parent_id + "' in parents"` is used for the search query, will all files be retrieved in the folder?

Comment: yes, that is just the case.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, when `pageSize` is increased, what result will you obtain?

Comment: I don't really see a different behaviour. I am still not able to detect files with calendar week between 10 and 19. When I change the name to 'CW010' for example, my code is able to detect the files again. But that would be a stupid workaround :/